# Slow Linux machine

Tags: linux, performance

Every time I login (via `ssh`) in my Linux/debian computer it takes too long for the password prompt to appear. Also, every time I try to run a python script or a `tcpdump` it takes too long until it starts.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Get a faster computer or reduce the load on the one you have

Comment: Have you tried any diagnostic tools (e.g., `top`) to determine if the system is under load and if so, from what?

Comment: Some hangs could depend on dns requests. At least try to disable dns check in sshd: `UseDNS no`

Comment: Is it faster if you use the computer directly, not by ssh? Could it be that the SSH connection is slow, not the computer?

Comment: You could also try `iotop`.

Comment: Don't disable dns checks, make sure that you have a working resolver.

Answer (score 3):

Collect all required information with monitoring commands:

- `top` → Current load and which processes consumes most of the cpu/memory
- `free -m` → Field under `buffers/cache`: Current memory status
- `df -h` → Check, if some of the local partitions running out of space

Useful resources:

```
ps aux --sort -rss   sort most used processes by memory
ps aux | sort -kr 3,3 | head -n 6 sort most 6 used processes by CPU
```

- `sar -u 1 1` → CPU usage by user, OS and idle
- `uptime` → Current load. Keep in mind that values are in 1 min, 5 min and 15 min average
- cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep processor → Number of processors (cores) you have on the machine, you can check. Calculate the load according to number of CPU, e.g `load=3 3 cores` it is ok, but you should check e.g `load=6 3 cores` this is critical.

Also `vmstat` and `htop` are useful commands:

Comment: For the processor count I'd suggest `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo` to get the relevant information without redundancy.

Comment: The OP doesn't say how long "too long" is, but as others above, I suspect that sshd is trying to inverse resolve the DNS name from the IP address of the ssh client and eventually times out because it fails. If this is what the problem is, none of your diagnostic commands will show anything because the resolver is just waiting for a timer to go off and is using almost no system resources (±0)

Comment: @msw " Also, every time I try to run a python script or a tcpdump it takes too long until it starts.." from the question, this is done on machine itself (at least how i understood), resolver can be the problem so that some of the commands go into the timed out, but it isalways caused by some process which slows the machine